# Replace a set of characters from the URL in apache rewrite rules

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write a generic rewrite rule that replaces a set of characters. I need to replace all "---" or "--" that are present in the url with "-"

Example 1:

```
Input: /Internal/Products/Alternative-Investments---new/
Output: /Internal/Products/Alternative-Investment-new/
```

Example 2:

```
Input: /Internal/Products/Clearing-Firms---new/New--page
Output: /Internal/Products/Clearing-Firms-new/New-page
```

The following is one of my attempts but it throws an error

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Internal/Products
RewriteRule ^/Internal/Products/([^-]+)(.*)$ /Internal/Products/$1-$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^/Internal/Products(.*) /internal/products/${$lc:$1} [R,L]
```

Error:

```
'^/Internal/Products/([^-]+)(.*)$' and URI 
'/Internal/Products/Alternative-Investments---new/' exceeded maximum length (16380)
```

Comment: This sounds as if you are trying to handle the symptom instead of curing the cause...

Comment: This is a redo of an old website, but we need these redirects in case someone tries to access the site using old URLs. This is the requirement here

Comment: As per [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283057/mod-rewrite-questions-getting-migrated-to-sf) and [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283033/are-htaccess-questions-ever-on-topic-at-so) this question is not at all off-topic for SO so close vote is wrong. This has been discussed again and again and it has been settled already that most of the rewrite rules are created and maintained by developers of the web applications/frameworks.

Comment: Moreover this problem requires use of regex to solve it, there is no other way to solve, so it is important to have `regex` tag in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteMap lc int:tolower

# recursively remove 2+ hyphens with a single one and set DONE flag
RewriteRule ^(/?Internal/Products/.+)-{2,}(.*)$ $1-$2 [N,NC,DPI,E=DONE:1]

# when DONE flag is set perform a redirect and lowercase URL
RewriteCond %{ENV:DONE} =1
RewriteRule ^/?(Internal/Products)/(.+)$ /$1/${lc:$2} [R=301,NE,L]

# if URL has an uppercase letter then lowercase full URL
RewriteRule ^/?(Internal/Products)/(.*[A-Z].*)$ /$1/${lc:$2} [R=301,NE,L]
```